# Does Room optimize out nested transactions? If not, how to remove the begin/endTransaction calls?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

When I write a DAO and add an insert method, the implementation can be found in a generated file. An example of this can be the following implementation:

```
@Override
public Object insert(final DbUser entity, final Continuation<? super Unit> continuation) {
  return CoroutinesRoom.execute(__db, true, new Callable<Unit>() {
    @Override
    public Unit call() throws Exception {
      __db.beginTransaction();
      try {
        __insertionAdapterOfDbUser.insert(entity);
        __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
      } finally {
        __db.endTransaction();
      }
    }
  }, continuation);
}
```

Here you can see it ALWAYS starts a transaction. My question is: can I annotate the method or do ANYTHING to remove that transaction? I want to do this because I think it's unnecessary since I already wrap all the database related stuff inside my own `runInTransaction` block, this just slows down everything.

Comment: My bad about that one, I misinterpreted an annotation. The other thing ok - just dig through it yourself - the code is open source so you can see whether nested transactions are accounted for. Also if you want that DEEP managing of the database, no one is stopping you.